# Why has the site not launched yet?

Tags: discussion

I see many quality questions and answers on this site , it is really suprising to see that the site is still in the beta.  Has the the SE team reviewed it for maturity? if yes then what is required to launch this site?

Comment: The site is still quite young in SE terms.

Answer (score 5):

It takes a lot more than questions and answers to make a Stack Exchange site succeed.  Our biggest problem is, as it has been for a while, a lack of engaged experts who can actually self-govern the site.

If you look at our [Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) you'll see that even this late, we *still* only have 132 users who have even reached the 200 reputation level; we've had a small handful of dedicated users since the beginning, but there's little indication that we're attracting and engaging many new ones.

And now, many of our dedicated users have gone off to do other things.

As a moderator, I still often find myself being needed to moderate issues that, ideally, could be done by the regular users.  Common tasks such as closing and deleting questions are all in the hands of regular users with enough rep, yet it's still rare to see a poor question garner 5 votes-to-close, or a very-low-quality/not-an-answer post with even a single downvote.

Until we have enough users who not only have the reputation to self-moderate, not only know how to self-moderate effectively, but actually care enough about the site to do so, we'll remain in beta.

I would also recommend you read the following blog post: [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)